# How to make Jenkins build fail when a pytest test fails

Tags: python, jenkins, pytest

Here's my sample test code. When I run this in python version prior to 3.6, the test fails due to syntax error around Type checking.

Here's the error

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
collected 0 items / 1 errors

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________________ ERROR collecting test/test_status.py _____________________
lib/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:450: in _importtestmodule
    mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
lib/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:701: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
E     File "/home/jenkins-slave/workspace/.../test/test_status.py", line 11
E       test_client: FlaskClient = app.test_client()
E                  ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.14 seconds ============================
```

How do I make Jenkins build fail when this test fails?

Comment: `pytest` exits with code 2 on collection errors, so Jenkins should abort by default (AFAIK Jenkins aborts on first non-zero exit code). Double-check the job, I suppose the real issue lies somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks! I modified the script calling jenkins job to return the exit code. By default it was returning exit code 0.